# Unable to compile Roslyn project

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-assembly, roslyn

Today I have installed Roslyn September 2012 CTP. I began with a sample console project. After the IDE finished creating the project code, I pressed F5. I ended up with a dozen compilation errors saying none of the Roslyn namespaces found. However the intellesence options are working fine for those references.

I tried with restarting the Visual Studio and even the my PC as per suggestions I found elsewhere. But none could resolve this. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Set your target framework to match what is expected. This usually happens to me when Visual Studio is targeting .NET 4 (for example) but the project was written in .NET 4.5 or a project reference.

Comment: Thanks Simon. After changing to 4.5 it is working.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You should consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @svick Took your advice. I guess it's a good idea since most people will scroll past the comments looking for an answer. Will keep that in mind in future! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rep whoring :)

As posted in the comments, this generally happens when there is a .NET Framework target mismatch. Your Visual Studio will be targeting a different version of .NET than what the project or a project reference was developed in.

Comment: I am just wondering why the include reference tool showing these reference if they are build and available on 4.5. Is that a bug in VS?

Comment: I can't say for certain sorry. Possibly. All I know is that this exact issue has happened to me before.. and that was the cause.